# PySpark remove special chars in all col names for all special chars - error cannot resolve given column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to remove special characters from names in a dataframe created from a csv.  There are 100's of columns some with long names. I've tried a number of approaches all returning an error on at least one of the columns?

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferschema", "true") \
  .option("delimiter", ",").load(getArgument('sourceCSVpath') + getArgument('sourceCSV'))

df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z$]+","",col)) for col in df.columns])

temp_df1 = df.select([F.col(col).alias(col.replace('- ', '')) for col in df.columns])
```

**ERROR**
cannot resolve '`Organization - No. Of Employees - Employee Figures Date`' given input columns

```
Domestic Ultimate Employee Information Scope Code,NACE Revision 2 Description - Priority 4,NACE Revision 2 Description - Priority 5,NACE Revision 2 Description - Priority 6,Organization - No. Of Employees - Employee Figures Date,Number of Employees Scope Text,Organization Founded Date,NACE Revision 2 Description - Priority 1
9067,,,,,Headquarters Only (Employs Here),1997,Hospital activities
9067,,,,,Headquarters Only (Employs Here),1997,Hospital activities
9067,,,,,Headquarters Only (Employs Here),1997,Hospital activities
9067,,,,,Headquarters Only (Employs Here),1997,Hospital activities
9067,,,,,Headquarters Only (Employs Here),1997,Hospital activities
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added sample data to post above

Comment: if the CSV is not that big, you always can use Pandas to rename those columns, then use Spark to process it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove dots (or any other unwanted characters) from the column names you can use [DataFrame.toDF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF.html):

```python
temp_df1 = df.toDF(*[re.sub("\.", "", col) for col in df.columns])
```

`toDF` only takes the order of the columns into account. The original names of the columns which could cause troubles in a select statement are not used.

Comment: @anky the actual problem is the dot `.` in one of the columns (and I have updated my answer). If you use this column name in a select statement, Spark cannot distinguish the name `a.b` from a column called `a` that contains a struct with a member `b`. Thats why a `select(a.b).alias(c)` does not work. When using `toDF(...)` all existing column names are replaced by new ones without selecting any of the existing columns before.

Comment: Nice, got it now. Thank you +1